# Edit keyboard shortcut does nothing

Tags: bug, keyboard-shortcuts

I have the Keyboard Shortcut* feature enabled. I normally only used the shortcuts for navigating through posts, but another Meta question had me testing the "Edit" option.

So, I went to a post I knew I would be able to edit or suggest an edit on, and I opened the help menu to ensure that this *is* an option and to make sure I hit the right key.

[image: Shortcut menu for posts]

Sure enough, there's the edit option. I already had the post I wanted to edit selected, hit the <kbd>E</kbd> on my keyboard and...

Nothing. Thinking this may be an issue with Meta specifically, I went to main and tried this on a post there. Same result. The page doesn't attempt to load the editor or refresh or anything. It's as if I didn't push a button.

Thinking maybe this was a problem with *answers,* I pulled up a question instead and tried the same. Still nothing. To narrow this down further, I went to Meta Stack Exchange and enabled the shortcuts there.

I found a post and hit the button, and the page redirected to the editor for that post. So this works *fine* on Meta Stack Exchange, but not on Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Overflow.

I am using Chrome Version 48.0.2564.97 m on Windows 7 with no extensions enabled. I see no errors on the console and everything looks fine in my dev tools.

I downloaded Firefox 44 to test this in, and the issue is not present in Firefox 44. IE 11 also appears to not have this issue. This appears to *only* be present in Chrome.

---

<sub>* For those not already aware who wish to test this, you can enable the Keyboard Shortcuts in your profile settings. The option is under the "Preferences" category.</sub>

Comment: Have been using keyboard shortcuts in meta. I can use E to edit easily. (I typed this using C :-)) (FF41 Ubu15.10)

Comment: @BhargavRao Everything else I've used has been working, the only one that isn't for me is E. Out of curiosity, are you on the new nav? (I have a theory this may have something to do with it, since it works fine on MSE for me.)

Comment: Yes, I am on new-nav. I can edit on both SO and MSO.

Comment: Then that tells me new nav is not the issue here, thanks!